# OS Error when trying to connect to local sever from my android emulator, but my emulator has internet and DNS is correct

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, emulation

I am using an android studio emulator that has internet connection and the play store which I downloaded Ping tools and could go to different sites. When I ping my local computer I get DNS error and when using either android studio of visual studio code I can see I am getting an OS Error. I also tried setting the DNS as my local computer. Any ideas?

Comment: What IP are you using?  The IP of the host?  That's wrong, because there's no actual network connection there.  You'd need to use 10.0.2.2 to ping the host machine, which would use the tunnel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.